# Обработка событий в консоли Java (IDE : IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, консоль

Можно ли в консоли *IntelliJ IDEA* производить какое-то действие при нажатии на определенную кнопку?

К примеру. У нас есть меню:

1. Roll_one
2. Roll_ten
3. Roll_ten

Нам нужно, чтобы при нажатии 1, 2 или 3 вызывался тот или иной метод.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
int number = scanner.nextInt();
switch (number) {
case 1:
    roll_one();
    break;
case 2:
    roll_two();
    break;
case 3:
    roll_three();
    break;
defult: 
    System.out.println("Type 1, 2 or 3");
    break;
}
```

И загнать все это в цикл, если нужно.

Comment: Я немного не это подразумевал. Здесь идет просто считывание числа, то есть мы вводим его, а дальше программа ждем от нас подтверждения, то есть нажатие клавиши Enter, а мне интересен именно тот вариант, где мы может просто нажать число 1/2/3 и будет запущен один из нужных для нас вариантов. Можем ли мы реализовать так?

Comment: Reader читающий посимвольно не подойдет?

Comment: Можно пример, если не сложно?

Comment: @Виктор а разьве ридеру не надо передавать символ окончания строки?

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov если читать по 1 символу то не обязательно. Читал что так даже лучше, т.к. может не быть символа конца строки и readLine подвиснет